# EMF Eclipse Installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, emf

I keep getting the "no repository found at ..." error while trying to install emf through the install new software window. I'm not sure if the link I am using-->   http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/
is suitable for this purpose. Could someone please point me in the right direction of fixing this? Thanks.

Comment: The main update site for Eclipse should have EMF in the 'Modeling' section.

Comment: @greg-449 Do you mean http://www.eclipse.org/emf/ ? That didn't help me though...

Comment: No I mean http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler if you are using Eclipse Kepler. This should already be in your Available Software Sites lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can download an Eclipse Bundle with EMF intalled here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/keplersr2